# the then new robots

Tags: meaning, articles, adjectives

a. They used then-new robots.

b. They used **the** then-new robots.

Are both sentences grammatically correct?

I think they are, but there is a difference in their meanings.

To me, (a) means that they used robots that were new at the time.

(b) could mean either

1. They used robots, which at the time were new. (Robots were new things at the time, and they used robots.

or

2. They used the robots that were new at the time.

Is that correct?

Comment: Ignore the adjective phrase "then-new" and just consider the difference between "they used robots" and "they used **the** robots". This is just another question about the definite article, to use or not to use, and I'm sure you will find lots of existing questions and answers about this.

Comment: It's *possible* the article here might genuinely be implying a reference to some *specific* robots (which were new at the time). But it's also possible the reference is a more "generic" one (*robots in general* were new at that time) - and that meaning could apply ***regardless of whether the article is included.***

Comment: The only difference here is the normal difference between using "the" versus no article.